# What mvn plugin to use that would help to set a dynamic value for a property?

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho

I have a pom.xml mvn configuration file that compiles some eclipse plugins. 
I am looking for adding in my configuration a simple mvn plugin that would set value for a variable, a property that will be used later in next running maven plugin.

E.g. if I run from command line

```
mvn clean verify -Ddebug=true
```

the property should get one value, e.g. `PATH_VALUE=<some_path1>`
and then if I run

```
mvn clean verify
```

the property should get other value, e.g. `PATH_VALUE=<some_path2>`, because the debug=false by default.

That's it, should be simple and should be possible. How to do it?
One dynamic value that may have 2 possibilities based on true/false flag that was used during run time.

Comment: why not pass directly the property value in the command: "mvn clean verify -DPATH_VALUE=..." ?

Comment: Thanks Fouad, that actually also works for me. I can set default value for the property. If nothing has been provided from command line, default value is used, if I use -DVALUE_PATH= in command line, default value is overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default value in the `<properties>` section of the `pom.xml`.